# "Meson failed" while generating core-image-selinux in yocto warrior branch

Tags: yocto, selinux, meson-build

While generating `core-image-selinux` for yocto warrior branch, I am getting below error,

```
ERROR: glib-2.0-native-1_2.58.3-r0 do_configure: meson failed
ERROR: glib-2.0-native-1_2.58.3-r0 do_configure: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/panther2/warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/glib-2.0-native/1_2.58.3-r0/temp/log.do_configure.34545)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/panther2/warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/glib-2.0-native/1_2.58.3-r0/temp/log.do_configure.34545
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| NOTE: Executing meson -Ddtrace=false -Dfam=false -Dsystemtap=false -Dselinux=false -Dlibmount=true -Dman=false -Dselinux=disabled -Dinternal_pcre=false -Dinstalled_tests=false...
| The Meson build system
| Version: 0.49.2
| Source dir: /home/panther2/warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/glib-2.0-native/1_2.58.3-r0/glib-2.58.3
| Build dir: /home/panther2/warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/glib-2.0-native/1_2.58.3-r0/build
| Build type: native build
|
| meson.build:1:0: ERROR:  Value disabled is not boolean (true or false).
|
| A full log can be found at /home/panther2/warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/glib-2.0-native/1_2.58.3-r0/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
| ERROR: meson failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/panther2/warrior/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/glib-2.0-native/1_2.58.3-r0/temp/log.do_configure.34545)
```

This is what I have done:

- Cloned `poky`, `meta-openembedded` and `meta-selinux` for warrior branch
- Ran `source poky/oe-init-build-env`
- Added below layers in `bblayers.conf`

  /home/panther2/warrior/meta-openembedded/meta-python \

  /home/panther2/warrior/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \

  /home/panther2/warrior/meta-selinux \
- Added below lines in `local.conf`

  DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " acl xattr pam selinux"
  PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/refpolicy ?= "refpolicy-mls"
- Executed `bitbake core-image-selinux` and got above error

Any help is really appreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: It seems [meson-enable-selinux.bbclass](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-selinux/tree/classes/meson-enable-selinux.bbclass?h=warrior) is broken as it should contain `PACKAGECONFIG[selinux] = "-Dselinux=true,-Dselinux=false,libselinux,"` ?

Comment: `bitbake -e core-image-selinux | grep ^EXTRA_OEMESON` doesn't show anything.

Comment: With `PACKAGECONFIG[selinux] = "-Dselinux=true,-Dselinux=false,libselinux,"` I am getting another error. i.e.
`ERROR: core-image-selinux-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Postinstall scriptlets of ['busybox'] have failed. If the intention is to defer them to first boot,
then please place them into pkg_postinst_ontarget_${PN} ().
Deferring to first boot via 'exit 1' is no longer supported.
Details of the failure are in /home/panther2/warrior/build/tmp-glibc/work/qemux86-oe-linux/core-image-selinux/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.`

Comment: New error, maybe related to this [bug](https://www.mail-archive.com/openembedded-core@lists.openembedded.org/msg126386.html)

Comment: Following [patch](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-selinux/commit/?h=warrior&id=988f58701697876cde0f640023390cc65a7a59a5) fixes Warrior branch.